# Android SQLite Error Inicio Sesion

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite

Cuando ejecuto la app me da error, y se sale de la misma. Es un login para enviar a otro MainActivity, este es el código de la función entrar, donde me da el error:

```
public void entrar (View view) {
    String user = et1.getText().toString();
    String password = et2.getText().toString();

    if(password.length() == 0 || user.length() == 0) {
        Toast error = Toast.makeText(this, R.string.alert1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        error.show();
    } else {
        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper conex = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "buscaminasbd", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase bd = conex.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor fila = bd.rawQuery( //cogemos la fila donde coincide el nombre
                "select puntos from usuarios where nombre=" + user, null);

        if(fila.moveToFirst()) { //devuelve un boolean si es true devuelve sino false
            Integer puntosj = fila.getInt(0);
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);

            i.putExtra("nombre", user);
            i.putExtra("puntos", puntosj);

            startActivity(i);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.alert4, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        bd.close();
    }
}
```

Mi código AdminSQLiteOpenHelper:

```
public class AdminSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table usuarios(nombre text primary key, pass text, puntos int)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Andres, podrías poner cual es el error que te sale por favor.

Comment: Hola Andres, No noto problemas en la creación, scripts u obtención de datos, Son muchas las posibles causas, es demasiado importante agregar el LogCat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo General la Aplicación se detiene por un dato NULL.

Es difícil saber exactamente el error ya que no has facilitado el LogCat.

El Error pueden ser varias cosas una es que la Siguiente Main2Activity tenga errores no existe,que el Cursor sea null,etc.

Deberías usar System.out.println("Hay Resultados"); para debuguear y ver donde se detiene tu código, por otro lado veo que la forma en que realizas el String para tu query esta mal ya que la variable(user) debería ser parte de la misma cadena por así decirlo.

```
Cursor fila = bd.rawQuery( //cogemos la fila donde coincide el nombre
            "select puntos from usuarios where nombre="+user, null);
```

Actualmente esta asi,prueba con este ejemplo,tener en cuenta que un dato de tipo String debe siempre ir entre comillas simples.

```
Cursor fila = bd.rawQuery("select puntos from usuarios where nombre='"+user+"'", null);
```

Comment: Funcionó, gracias Emilio!

Answer (score 0):

Andres, creo que tu error está en la creación de la base de datos. Estás creando la tabla con la columna `puntos` como `int`, cambia por `integer`

Comment: Es aceptado usar int, al crear la tabla en Sqlite.

Comment: He usado integer y sigue sin funcionar, el error es que una vez hago click en el boton Entrar se cierra la aplicacion 'app has stoped'